# How I can integrate browser engine to my MASM app?

Tags: webbrowser-control, masm32

I'm developing an app on MASM using the RadASM IDE. This IDE comes with an IE control (WebBrowser) but the content that I want to display is broken on that browser (XHTML+CSS), also I want to remove the dependency of an external IE dll so the only solution that comes to my mind is use an engine of other browser like Firefox or Chrome.
I've searched over the net and I found some DevKits that meets my requeriments, but they are designed to work with VS2005+ or they just are coded on C++.

If someone know a way to integrate a browser engine (Not IE) to a MASM app, will be highly appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find any browser SDK that specifically helps you call it from assembly language. Almost nobody actually writes applications in assembly language today. However, C is pretty close to assembly, so all you have to do is use the instructions for C and translate to assembly language. Since you're already writing an application in assembly language, that should be no trouble for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any SDK that comes with pre-compiled binaries using the WinAPI functions **LoadLibraryA** and **GetProcAddress**. Or you can build your own import libraries for MASM by following what either [Iczelion did write on that topic](http://win32assembly.online.fr/importlib.html) (definately worth a read) or by reading the [3 part guide](http://www.sascha-hennig.de/masm/using-the-fmod-api-with-masm-part-13) on my website, which is based on Iczelions guide but works on a live example, namely creating your own MASM import library for the FMOD API.

Weather it is worth all the hassle is another question.